# Cocoa - calling a VIEW method from the CONTROLLER

Tags: cocoa, view, controller

Got a little problem i asked about it before but maybe i didnt ask properly.
I have a cocoa application, which amongst other things, must do the following task:
- load some images from the disk, store them in an array and display them in a custom view.

In the Interface Builder i have a CustomView and an OBJECT that points to TexturesController.h

The custom view is a custom class, TextureBrowser.
Below is the code for the controller and view:

**TexturesController**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class TextureBrowser;

@interface TexturesController : NSObject {  
  IBOutlet NSTextField *logWindow;  
  IBOutlet TextureBrowser *textureView;
  NSMutableArray *textureList; 
} 
@property textureView;
-(IBAction)loadTextures:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)showTexturesInfo:(id)sender;
@end
```

**TextureBrowser**

```
@interface TextureBrowser : NSView {
  NSMutableArray *textures;
}
@property NSMutableArray *textures;
-(void)loadTextureList:(NSMutableArray *)source;
@end
```

These are just the headers. Now , what i need to do is:

- when loadTextures from the TexturesController is called, after i load the images i want to send this data to the view (TextureBrowser), for example, store it in the NSMutableArray *textures.

I tried using the -(void)loadTextureList:(NSMutableArray*)source method from the view, but in the TextureController.m i get a warning : No -loadTextureList method found

This is how i call the method :

```
[textureView loadTextureList: textureList];
```

And even if i run it with the warning left there, the array in the view class doesnt get initialised.

Maybe im missing something...maybe someone can give a simple example of what i need to do and how to do it (code).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some of TextureView.h so we can see the @interface.

Comment: the TextureView is the TextureBrowser ... must it be called with View in the end?

Thanks for the formatting Geoff, i couldnt figure it out :)

Comment: Does TexturesController.m import TextureBrowser.h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `TexturesController.m`, you have to import `TextureBrowser.h` so that the controller knows what methods the property `textureView` has. Right now, you've just got a blank placeholder symbol instead of an actual class.

Since `textureView` is defined by an outlet, you need to make sure that its class is properly set in Interface Builder. If you provide a generic NSView instead, it won't have the `loadTextureList:` method.

Comment: Thanks, this almost did it, now the method in the View is called. I still have another problem though.
Im loading the textures using NSFileManager, which returns an array with the files.
Then in in a for cycle, im updating the textureList array with the values from the array returned earlier by NSFileManager.
I do this by calling: [textureList addObject:....]
The problem is at the end of the cycle, [textureList count] returns 0.
Maybe there is a better way to copy the array returned from NSFileManager to my textureList array? And what am i doing wrong here that makes textureList have a 0 size?

Comment: Found the problem myself, didnt alloc the array .

Thanks again everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you imported TextureBrowser.h in TexturesController.m, I don't see why it wouldn't find your method.

But why don't you simply call `self.textureView.textures = textureList;` from the TexturesController ?

Comment: I just tried this, im getting an error:

accessing unknown 'textureView' getter method

Comment: Eugh - what about encapsulation?

Comment: How would i use encapsulation?